# Running a shell subscript as the parent script's user

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, tomcat

If I want to call another shell script within a main script file as a particular user, how do I go about doing it? The child script seems to loose context of what user it is running as and I haven't found any useful sub-scripting techniques.

Ex: war-install.sh

```
if [ ! -d /opt/tomcat/ ]
then
   ./tomcat-install-files/install.sh
fi
```

The problem here is that if I run war-install.sh as root or with the sudo command, ./tomcat-install-files/install.sh seems to lose the sudo/root context. How can I rectify this?

Thanks!

Comment: It shouldn't (change users), unless the sub-commands are themselves setuid (bad idea if shell script!).  What makes you think it is losing the sudo user?

Comment: If I run the command "sudo ./tomcat-install-files/install.sh", the script runs fine. But if I run "sudo war-install.sh", once it calls install.sh, I get a bunch of "permission denied" errors.

Comment: Is the above the entire contents of war-install.sh?  Does /opt/tomcat/ exist as a directory?  Assuming "no" (there's more) and "no" (so it does reach the ./ line), is "." still pointing to the same place at that point?  (Try setting -x and/or doing a `pwd` there before invoking ./tomcat-install-files/install.sh.)

Comment: The example above is the first thing that runs. I added a pwd before I call the subscript and I get "/home/roosh", and as the first line in the subscript I get "/home/roosh/tomcat-install-files". The first thing I try to do in the subscript is create /opt/tomcat (mkdir -p /opt/tomcat/). I get "mkdir: cannot create directory `/opt/tomcat': Permission denied" because root owns /opt.

Comment: Wow. ... Hm, I wonder ... is /home/roosh mounted nosuid?  Now I have to go see whether that would affect anything...

Comment: I'm by no means an expert at Unix, is there a way to tell how the directory is mounted? I am not the owner of the machine, I just have sudoer access. I have not tried to move the script to a directory that root owns and re-running it. Not sure if it will make a difference or not.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8748/discussion-between-torek-and-roosh)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Roosh that something weird is going on. But in general to run a command as another user:

`sudo -l <user> <cmd>`

Comment: If the sub-script runs the su command, the execution of all scripts is halted.

Comment: That should be `sudo`, not `su` (`su` will open an interactive shell, that's not what you want in a script).

Answer (score 0):

try with a space after the dot

```
if [ ! -d /opt/tomcat/ ]
then
   . /tomcat-install-files/install.sh
fi
```